# .NET Replace() doesn´t work

Tags: asp.net, replace

Hi i´m parsing aspx file to XML and i have this code:

```
if (lineLower.StartsWith("</asp:content>")) || (lineLower.StartsWith("</asp:Content>") && lineLower.EndsWith(">")))
                                    {
                                        temp += line.Replace(line, " ");
                                    }
```

But this **temp += line.Replace(line, " ");** will just add a space before **< /asp:content>** instead of replacing it byt space.

Do i need to use different syntax?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your IF logic looks shaky and as per LeZohan68 answer this will not even compile.

Comment: Any reason you're not using an actual XML parser, such as the [XmlDocument class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Also, isn't `temp += line.Replace(line, " ");` exactly the same as `temp += " ";`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have this

```
if (lineLower.StartsWith("</asp:content>"))
```

You're closing your `if` too soon

Try this

```
if (lineLower.StartsWith("</asp:content>") || (lineLower.StartsWith("</asp:Content>") && lineLower.EndsWith(">"))
                                {
                                    temp += line.Replace(line, " ");
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You coded it way too complicated

Just do this:

```
if (line.ToLower().StartsWith("</asp:content>") && line.EndsWith(">")))
{
    temp += " ";
}
```

Not even sure if you need this part : line.EndsWith(">")